# AWS CloudWatch — Signature Expired

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Everything is going fine, except one of my instances gives me the below error:

> **ubuntu@my-host:~$** /etc/aws-scripts-mon/mon-put-instance-data.pl --mem-util --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ --aws-credential-file=/etc/aws-scripts-mon/awscreds.template
>
> ERROR: Failed to call CloudWatch: HTTP 400. Message: Signature expired: 20150515T204709Z is now earlier than 20150515T204917Z (20150515T205417Z - 5 min.)

For more information, run 'mon-put-instance-data.pl --help'
I've tried searching around the Internet, including this link, but no luck. Any ideas?

One hint: I have a cron job invoking this same command every 5 minutes. It is also unsuccessful. That may be related to the x - 5 min. message bit in the above error message.

Answer (score 1):

The system time of the problem EC2 instance is off by several minutes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703486/aws-sdk-error-signature-not-yet-current

This turned out to solve my problem!